# How to set up 2 project website in nginx [im using nuxt run diffent port]

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, nginx, nuxt.js

Here is my structure folder

- var

  - www

    - html

      - backoffice
      - frontend

My projects are in backoffice and frontend

Im using pm2 to start my server port 3000, 3100

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /admin {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/admin;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

the path / is fine . The problem is in my /admin  It's turn into white screen

In nuxt when I npm run build It will compile into .nuxt folder

the problem are here when I run /admin path It run at port 3001

I try to debug by inspect element my js path

```
/_nuxt/921cc8ac0d041c1ae8a6.js
```

and when I click into link It's

```
/* script not found */
```

the problem are here  I think It's run port 3000 in stead of 3100 that's why It cant read any Css in /admin or 3001 port

How can I fix this

Comment: Please share the package.json, nuxt.config.js file to inspect the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add this into my nuxt.config.js

```
router: {
  base: '/admin/'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for Nuxt3, you can configure `app.baseURL` or set the env variable `NUXT_APP_BASE_URL`.

Here the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#baseurl).